# Ubuntu Web Font on Windows

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts

I am using Ubuntu Web Font for my website and the fonts look fine on Linux and Mac OS X but on Windows they render differently. The main problem with fonts on Windows is with alphabets 'g' and 'q'. One can hardly differentiate between the two.
Here's what the font-face definition looks like in my stylesheet

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'UbuntuRegular';
 src: url('assets/Ubuntu-Regular-webfont.eot');
 src: url('assets/Ubuntu-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('assets/Ubuntu-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),  url('assets/Ubuntu-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),  url('assets/Ubuntu-Regular-webfont.svg#UbuntuRegular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

And this is the style definition for the body

```
body {
    background:#1a1a1a;
    font-family:'UbuntuRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Would take too much convincing to too many people. The font suggestion was from the other party. Using something else would be the dead last solution.

Comment: I'm sure there're loads of Windows-specific issues, such as one mentioned in [Fluid Images](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images) about Windows being unable to scale images properly.